#  Two Table Query in Groovy script

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails, join, groovy

How do I handle this SQL query in grails in my ProductsController script?  Notice its two tables with a join on the product id.

```
SELECT p.*,pd.* 
FROM products p, products_description pd 
WHERE p.products_id=pd.products_id
ORDER BY p.products_date_added DESC
```

Obviously I can't do this:

```
def all= {
    def a
     a = Products.find("FROM products p, products_description pd 
      WHERE p.products_id=pd.products_id ORDER BY p.products_date_added DESC")
     render a as JSON
}
```

Comment: Would you stop editing my title its a Groovy script not GORM finder, hence the file I am editing is ProductsCopntroller.groovy  ...

Comment: It's a Grails controller where you are trying to write a finder, interacting with the GORM. The fact it is in groovy is more of a side effect, however if you wish to leave it with a less accurate title, then so be it...

Comment: Less experienced than yourself will search for Groovy script more so than GORM finder...that's what I would search for.  This is the first I heard of GORM finder...

Comment: And if they are actually looking for a standalone groovy solution, this will be less than no help... [GORM underpins Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adamant on using a custom sql query instead of any grails dynamic finder, you can use the following code:

```
    def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() // a reference to the sessionFactory is injected in all controllers and services that have a sessionFactory variable defined
     Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT p.*,pd.* 
     FROM products p, products_description pd 
     WHERE p.products_id=pd.products_id
     ORDER BY p.products_date_added DESC");
     def result = query.list()
```

You will have to add a variable named sessionFactory to your controller. Something like this:

```
    class ProductsController = {
      def sessionFactory
```

The result list would be a list of lists. Each element of the main list would be a list of size 2 with the first element as the product and the second as the product description.

Comment: I followed your example and got this error:ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /mygrails/prods/all
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1

Comment: Nevermind figured out why, seems it was having an issue with Text column so I changed the type from Text to Varchar (10000).  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to map a string to a text field in the database you need to specify that in the mapping closure. You will have to add <your field name> type : 'text' in the mapping closure in your domain class

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Many-to-one and one-to-one](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#5.2.1.1%20Many-to-one%20and%20one-to-one) relation and let GORM take care of the association for you.

```
class Products {
    ProductsDescription description
    ...
    static mapping = {
        description column: 'products_id'
    }
}
```

You can then access the description by reference:

```
a = products.listOrderByProductsDateAdded(order: 'desc')
a.description.productsDescription
```

Comment: Sorry this won't work as I can't define the relationships as the table is already set and I have to Jon by SQL query...I am connecting to a legacy DB and so the code for each of the tables is locked down.

Comment: @JPM That's what I assumed.  That's why I included a static mapping for your foreign key.

Comment: That doesn't compile it errors on the Products class with 'Cannot treat multi-column property as a single-column property'

Comment: Issue is legacy tables have id column name is product_id not id.  I have run into so many issues with that and most solutions to join in the class files don't work since this is not a true ORM database.

Comment: I tried your example by making the tables more GORM friendly and I still can't get it to work  I get this error Unknown column 'this_.products_id' in 'field list'